# Why is my read only field editable?

Tags: apex, visualforce, administration

I need to make one field(Date)  read-only in an object(Service Appointment).

I've set the Page layout settings to "Read-only"

I've unchecked the system permissions of profile  "Edit Read-only field"

I've given "No access"  to the object for that profile

I've restricted the access to the field from the "Field Level Security Settings" also

Still the field  can be edited.

Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: Is this using a Visualforce page or a standard layout?

Comment: Are you sysadmin? What is the profile? Also, are you using lightning? Did you try to clean the cache?

Comment: There was an issue with Profiles last weekend. Could be this?

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=some-user-profiles-and-permission-sets-were-modified-by-salesforce&Id=a1p3A000001SHDl

Comment: Hi @PhilW  it is using standard layout.

Comment: Hi @mPeixoto  i'm system admin but i tried it with other profile.Yes it is regarding Field service lightning of Gantt Chart.